# How to count number of times someone's tenure falls into each month range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of months someone's tenure falls into each range but am struggling to come up with a formula that works. For example:

```
Year-End Tenure      Year-Start Tenure       Month 1-6     Month 7-12    Month 13-24
23                   12                      0             1             12
56                   45                      0             0             0
11                   0                       6             5             0
```

The first employee starts the year having worked for this company for 12 months and ends the year having 23 months tenure. Therefore, they spent 0 months in the Month 1-6 bracket, 1 month in the Month 7-12 bracket, and 12 months in the Month 13-24 bracket.

The following two examples follow the same logic. I need a formula to calculate the numbers in Month 1-6, Month 7-12, and Month 13-24 columns.

Comment: If you have Office 365 look into SEQUENCE and SUMPRODUCT

Comment: Perhaps check out countifs()

Answer (score 1):

One answer using Excel 365. Most of the work is in splitting the headers up into start month and end month.

```
=LET(yStarts,B2:B4,
yEnds,A2:A4,
mRanges,C1:E1,
smRanges,SUBSTITUTE(mRanges,"Month ",""),
mStarts,MAP(smRanges,LAMBDA(x,--INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"-"),1))),
mEnds,MAP(smRanges,LAMBDA(x,--INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"-"),2))),
overlap,IF(yEnds<mEnds,yEnds,mEnds)-IF(yStarts>mStarts,yStarts,mStarts)+1,
IF(overlap<0,0,overlap))
```

[image]